# How to setup GStreamer tests such as GstValidate in C

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, gstreamer, alpine-linux

**What is the best way to add unit-tests to a GStreamer 1.0 C language application?**

The app is built in Docker in a similar fashion to the various [GStreamer Tutorials](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/index.html).

[image: GStreamer]

I have focused on `GstCheck`, `GstHarness`, and `GstValidate`.
As I am not writing any new GStreamer plug-ins, `GstValidate` seems like the best initial option as per [this](https://blogs.gnome.org/tsaunier/2014/04/21/gst-validate-a-suite-of-tools-to-run-integration-tests-for-gstreamer-2/) example, yet I am unable to include `GstValidateRunner` or `GstValidateMonitor` as necessary.

Code:

```
GstValidateRunner *runner;
GstValidateMonitor *monitor;
```

Compile errors:

```
error: unknown type name 'GstValidateRunner'
   GstValidateRunner *runner;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: unknown type name 'GstValidateMonitor'
   GstValidateMonitor *monitor;
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am building with Dockerfiles for Alpine and/or Ubuntu as follows:

**Alpine Dockerfile** *(partial)*:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
    gstreamer \
    gstreamer-dev \
    gstreamer-tools \
    gst-libav \
    musl-dev \
    gcc
```

**Ubuntu Dockerfile** *(partial)*:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libgstreamer1.0-0 \
    gstreamer1.0 \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-base \
    gstreamer1.0-plugins-good \
    gstreamer1.0-libav \
    gstreamer1.0-tools \
    musl-dev \
    gcc
```

Is there an additional `gst-devtools` package for apt-get or apk that is not listed above?

Ideas, advice, and suggestions welcome. Many thanks.

Comment: I couldn’t find any ubuntu package for it seems like you will have to clone and install https://blogs.s-osg.org/running-gstreamer-regression-tests/

Comment: @PrabhakarLad, you're link is dead.
Download+unpacking from https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-validate/ seems like the best possible option.